# Sender email address cut short (SMTP python 2.7.9)

Tags: python-2.7, smtplib

I tried sending an email using the SMTP (Python 2.7.9).

The sender I provide is 'kmuthukumar@example.com', however in the receiver's inbox, the sender is cut short into 'ukumar@example.com', which is another existing user in our system.

Any idea what is causing this?

More info:
This issue only happens when emails are generated by code using 'kmuthukumar' as sender. Results are normal when kmuthukumar sends an email through email applications. The original code is working fine for all other users.

```
import time
from smtplib import SMTP
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

server='internal-smtp.example.com'
sender="kmuthukumar@example.com"
recipients = ['user@example.com']
cc=[]

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg["From"] = sender
msg["To"]=", ".join(recipients) if isinstance(recipients, list) else recipients
msg["Subject"] = "test"
msg['Date'] = time.ctime(time.time())

subtype='plain'
charset='utf-8'

message = "hello"
text = MIMEText(message, _subtype=subtype, _charset=charset)

msg.attach(text)

smtp = SMTP(server)
smtp.sendmail(sender, list(set(recipients+cc)), msg.as_string())
smtp.quit()
```

Comment: Have you authenticated through proper username and password?

Comment: ```server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("abc.xyz@example.com", "hahah")
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, rcpt, text)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried including a login, still having the same problem. Based on the original code, no login sessions were created, and it works fine for everything. The problem mentioned only happens when an email is generated from user 'kmuthukumar'.